# Why can't we return an ArrayList<Foo>.iterator() for Iterator<IFoo>?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a method which returns an `Iterator<IFoo>`. Inside that method, if I try to return `someArrayList` of type `ArrayList<Foo>`, I get a compilation error saying: 
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Foo> to Iterator<IFoo>`

Here's the type Hierarchy:

```
Interface:IFoo
--Class: Foo (Implements IFoo)
```

And, here's my method:

```
public Iterator<IFoo> iterator() {  
    return someArrayList.iterator();
}
```

My question is, when the method wants me to return something of type `Iterator<IFoo>`, why can't we return `someArrayList` of type `ArrayList<Foo>` since Foo implements `IFoo`?

### Update at 8:38 AM on Friday, June 20, 2014 (UTC)

The method in question `public Iterator<IFoo> iterator()` cannot be modified since I'm implementing an interface.

I should have mentioned this before. Sorry.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public <T extends IFoo> Iterator<T> iterator()`?

Comment: Short answer: generics are invariant. `SomeClass<SuperClass>` is *not* a superclass of `SomeClass<SubClass>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). But as @blueygh2 stated, changing the method declaration would allow your code to compile.

Comment: @blueygh2 and user3580294 Thanks for the helpful comments; but the problem still remains unsolved as I cannot modify the method signature. Please see the update to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your most recent edit, where you say you can't modify the method signature (which is really too bad, because a more flexible signature would have avoided this...):

One solution is to create a new `List` with the proper type and use the iterator from that. This works because the various constructors for lists are far more flexible in the types they accept and will take subtypes. The main disadvantage is that this will produce a shallow copy of your original `ArrayList`, which takes up extra space (albeit not too much unless you're working with very large lists). This is basically your posted answer in a much more compact form.

```
public Iterator<IFoo> iterator() {  
    return new ArrayList<IFoo>(someArrayList).iterator();
}
```

You have to specify the type arguments explicitly here because otherwise the type will be inferred to be `Foo`, which just leaves you back where you were.

Alternatively, if the extra space required by the `new ArrayList()` call isn't appealing, you can write an anonymous subclass of `Iterator` that simply acts as a wrapper (I *think* I got the syntax right; might have made a minor mistake or two, but those should be easy to fix). It's more writing, but it's leaner on memory usage, which might be desirable:

```
public Iterator<IFoo> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<IFoo>() {
        private final Iterator<? extends IFoo> iterator = someArrayList.iterator();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public Number next() {
            return iterator.next();
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    };
}
```

---

One important thing to note is that these solutions are not exactly equivalent.

Your solution and my first solution return iterators that operate on a *different* list than your original one. This distinct list is a shallow copy, so you'll get the same results from `hasNext()` and `next()`. However, if you call `remove()`, your original list will remain unaffected, and only the copy will be changed.

The anonymous subclass will perform all its operations on your original list, as if your original solution had worked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Generics doesnt work that way, you would need to use wildcards for it and/or boundaries.

```
public Iterator<? extends IFoo> iterator()
```

Comment: Thank you Edward. Problem is that I cannot modify the method signature... Please see the update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's basicly because Java generics are invariant. To make it possible to return generic subtypes, type-system should allow covariance. Without defining upper-bound of type, this won't work. Like pointed in earlier posts, this can be achieved by relaxing your type definition to allow subtypes returned:

```
public Iterator<? extends IFoo> iterator()
```

There is a good [article](http://blog.informatech.cr/2013/03/15/covariance-and-contravariance-in-java/%20article) about covariance and contravariance in Java, which also explains why this check has to be done at compile time.

Comment: Thank you smartoma. It's my fault that I had not given an important constraint in the question: I cannot modify the method signature... Please see the update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I (the poster of this question) did, given the constraint that I cannot modify the method `public Iterator<IFoo> iterator()`:

*Note: certain variables (e.g. `someArrayList`) relate to the question.*

```
public Iterator<IFoo> iterator() { 
    Iterator<Foo> fooIterator = someArrayList.iterator();
    ArrayList<IFoo> iFooList = new ArrayList<IFoo>();
    while (fooIterator.hasNext()) {
        IFoo iFoo = (IFoo) fooIterator.next();
        iFooList.add(iFoo);
    }
    return iFooList.iterator();
}
```

Please point out if this is a wrong way.

Comment: What happens if you replace all those lines with `return new ArrayList<IFoo>(list).iterator();`?

Comment: Thanks! That does NOT give any compilation errors :-) Can you please post your comment as an answer?